How do I configure an INSERT INTO query with multiple UNIONs across multiple databases and multiple servers
I have seen examples of INSERT queries that pull date from tables in multiple databases or multiple servers but I have not been successful in putting all of it together.
I have a query that uses multiple tables to generate a flattened table of the requested data.  I can run this on a single database on a single server with no issues.
The Goal is to expand this query to pull data from 9, databases across 6 servers.  The databases are all have an identical schema and formatting.
I don't have any issues when I have an INSERT and am using UNION with two databases on the same server.  When I try to add the second server that query shows as a fail.  Hovering over the table reference in the FROM statement I get "Invalid Object Name".  I built the object name by dragging over the elements from the Object Explorer to ensure there were no typo issues.
What I have now is:
INTO [Server1].[Database1].[dbo].[FlattenedTable] (field1, field2, field3.....)
(SELECT field1, field2, field3......
From [Server1],[Database2].[dbo].[Table1]
Inner Join [Server1],[Database2].[dbo].[Table2] on [Server1],[Database2].[dbo].[Table1].[Field1] = [Server1],[Database2].[dbo].[Table2].[Field1])
UNION
(SELECT field1, field2, field3......
From [Server1],[Database3].[dbo].[Table1]
Inner Join [Server1],[Database3].[dbo].[Table2] on [Server1],[Database3].[dbo].[Table1].[Field1] = [Server1],[Database3].[dbo].[Table2].[Field1])
UNION
(SELECT field1, field2, field3......
From [Server2],[Database3].[dbo].[Table1]
Inner Join [Server2],[Database3].[dbo].[Table2] on [Server2],[Database3].[dbo].[Table1].[Field1] = [Server2],[Database3].[dbo].[Table2].[Field1])
The entire query for the second server is underlined in red.  Hovering over the table reference in the FROM statement I get "Invalid Object Name".  I built the object name by dragging over the elements from the Object Explorer to ensure there were no typo issues.
I am hoping that I have a simple syntax issue - commas, parentheses, something - that is causing it to choke on that last UNION.
Again, the goal is that there will be 8 UNIONS bringing in data from 5 servers.

It looks like you're trying to use a four-part name to reference a table on a different server, but the syntax is not quite correct.
When referencing a table on a different server, you need to use a four-part name in the format:
[ServerName].[DatabaseName].[SchemaName].[TableName]
However, in your query, you have commas separating the server and database names, which is not correct.
Try changing the query to use the correct four-part name syntax, like this:
INTO [Server1].[Database1].[dbo].[FlattenedTable] (field1, field2, field3.....) ( SELECT field1, field2, field3......  FROM [Server1].[Database2].[dbo].[Table1]  INNER JOIN [Server1].[Database2].[dbo].[Table2]  ON [Server1].[Database2].[dbo].[Table1].[Field1] = [Server1].[Database2].[dbo].[Table2].[Field1] ) UNION ( SELECT field1, field2, field3......  FROM [Server1].[Database3].[dbo].[Table1]  INNER JOIN [Server1].[Database3].[dbo].[Table2]  ON [Server1].[Database3].[dbo].[Table1].[Field1] = [Server1].[Database3].[dbo].[Table2].[Field1] ) UNION ( SELECT field1, field2, field3......  FROM [Server2].[Database3].[dbo].[Table1]  INNER JOIN [Server2].[Database3].[dbo].[Table2]  ON [Server2].[Database3].[dbo].[Table1].[Field1] = [Server2].[Database3].[dbo].[Table2].[Field1] ) 
Also, make sure that the servers are linked and the databases are accessible from the server where you're running the query. You can check the linked servers by running the following query:
SELECT * FROM sys.servers
This will show you a list of linked servers. If the server you're trying to access is not listed, you'll need to add it as a linked server before you can access its databases.
Additionally, you may need to use the OPENQUERY function to execute the query on the remote server, like this:
SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY([Server2], 'SELECT field1, field2, field3...... FROM [Database3].[dbo].[Table1] INNER JOIN [Database3].[dbo].[Table2] ON [Database3].[dbo].[Table1].[Field1] = [Database3].[dbo].[Table2].[Field1]')
This will execute the query on the remote server and return the results to the local server.
